# Turn off Jupyter Notebook autosaving

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Before you flag this has duplicate, I want to point out that I did read the posts here and all of them tell me to change the code in

```
~/.jupter/custom/custom.js
```

However, there is no such directory as `custom` and no such file as `custom.js`

Also, if I add the above files and the code, then too it is autosaving.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: `jupyter version is : 4.3.0`
Operating System: `Ubuntu 16.04`
Installed via pip

Answer (score -1):

Put that in the `custom.js`:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ],
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("notebook_loaded.Notebook",
            function () {
                IPython.notebook.set_autosave_interval(0); //in milliseconds
            }
        );
        //may include additional events.on() statements
    }
);
```